# How to check if a Kmeans Model in Bigquery is done training using Bigquery Nodejs Client Library?

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I have an app that allows people to use a graphical user interface to create models in Bigquery, so I'm able to create the model by calling my nodejs APIS which call bigquery, the model takes some to train, how can i query bigquery to check whether my model is done training using my nodejs bigquery client library so i know the model is done training and i can start accessing the centroids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are able to train the model, there should be a corresponding `jobID` created for the training. What you can do is list the all the jobs and filter them by status in this case check the ones running.

Code below will return the running jobs:

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

const jobArr = []

async function listJobs() {
  // Lists all jobs in current GCP project.

  // List the 5 most recent "running" jobs in reverse chronological order.
  // Omit the max_results parameter to list jobs from the past 6 months.
  // set allUsers to true to display jobs owned by all users in the project.
  const options = {
                   maxResults: 5, 
                   allUsers: true, 
                   stateFilter: 'running' //Acceptable values are "done", "pending", and "running"
                  };

  const [jobs] = await bigquery.getJobs(options);

  console.log('Jobs:');
  jobs.forEach(job => {
          console.log(job.id)
  });
}
```

See [getJobs()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#getJobs) for further reference on how to use this method.

For testing purposes I ran a single job and it returned the currently running job. You can now use this jobID and store it somewhere to monitor if a job is finished or not by getting its job details.

```
Jobs:
bquxjob_12345_1234456
```

You can further check details of this job by using `bigquery.job()` to get details like email address that ran the job, statics (create time, start time, etc), etc. You can further check in [Job REST reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job) for information that you can pull from this.

Get the email address that ran the job:

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

const jobArr = []

async function listJobs() {
  // Lists all jobs in current GCP project.

  // List the 5 most recent "running" jobs in reverse chronological order.
  // Omit the max_results parameter to list jobs from the past 6 months.
  // set allUsers to true to display jobs owned by all users in the project.
  const options = {
                   maxResults: 5, 
                   allUsers: true, 
                   stateFilter: 'running' //Acceptable values are "done", "pending", and "running"
                  };
  const [jobs] = await bigquery.getJobs(options);

  console.log('Jobs:');
  jobs.forEach(job => {
          jobArr.push(job.id) // pushed the jobID in a list to pass to getjob()
          console.log(job.id)
  });
  getJob(jobArr)
}

async function getJob(jobArr) {
  // Get job properties.
        for (const element of jobArr) {
                const job = bigquery.job(element);
                const [jobResult] = await job.get();
                console.log("Email:")
                console.log(jobResult.metadata.user_email);
                // uncomment this part to show start and end time
                //console.log("Start Time (UNIX epoch):")
                //console.log(jobResult.metadata.statistics.startTime);
                //console.log("End Time (UNIX epoch):")
                //console.log(jobResult.metadata.statistics.endTime);
        }

}

listJobs()
```

See [job()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#job) for further reference on how to use this method.

Output:

```
Jobs:
bquxjob_12345_1234456
Email:
test_email@test.com
```